# What is the [cpu] tag intended use?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I was checking a question today and saw it with the [cpu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu) and wondering exactly *how it should be used* I read the excerpt which basically told me what a CPU is, not what the tag is useful for. Now, checking the questions I see several questions about monitoring the cpu, cpu usage, cpu temperature, where the only thing in common is that the questions have something related with the CPU, but I do not see how that could be useful for this site. Is there any intended use that I'm not seeing? What should be the tag excerpt/wiki?

Comment: It seems to be mostly about CPU usage (e.g., as in `top`).

Comment: @derobert - in that case is it not a duplicate of performance?

Comment: @slm Depends on how [tag:performance] is defined. E.g., if you want to know how much CPU time a program used for accounting purposes (e.g., bill for CPU usage) then that's probably not [tag:performance]. And [tag:performance] can probably include disk, network, etc. But yeah, the two tags probably overlap a lot. Probably a case where we'd need to start retagging and see if anything is left.

Comment: @derobert that sounds like a plan.

Comment: [tag:cpu-performance] might be a more useful tag name, though I am not sure if even that is specific enough.

Comment: fwiw tags actually should be kind of generic. It doesn't make sense to have super specific tags that hardly anyone is going to be looking at or posting questions with.

Comment: @slm - What about GPU performance? :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing more to it actually.
The CPU tag is for CPU related questions.

The CPU is the piece of hardware executing instructions, therefore subjects can be related to the CPU in different ways. One can ask about performance while the other about intel x86 architecture, both are CPU related.

To your question - programmers writing low-level code, security researchers, performance engineers are just a few examples of people might be interested in CPU related questions.